# pluploader update url from input value

Tags: jquery, plupload

I have a page with a file tree from where users can select a directory or sub-directory to where they wish to upload files using pluploader. I have the following code:

```
if($("#uploader_v5").length > 0){
        $("#uploader_v5").pluploadQueue({       
                runtimes : 'html5',
                url : 'pluploader/upload_to_directory.php',
                max_file_size : '3mb',
                chunk_size : '3mb',
                unique_names : false,
                dragdrop : true,
                rename: true,
                filters : [
                        {title : "Document files", extensions : "pdf,php,html,xml"},
                        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
                ],
                
                FilesAdded: function(editor,files){
                    alert(files);
                }
        });
    }
```

Now I need to pass the chosen directory path to the url, eg. *pluploader/upload_to_directory.php?directory=[chosen directory path]*

When a user click on a directory in the file tree, the value of a hidden input is updated with the full path.

So far it seems I'll need to add something like the code below:

```
$("#uploader_v5").bind('BeforeUpload', function(uploader, file) {
    uploader.settings.url = "pluploader/upload_to_directory.php?directory=[chosen directory]";
});
```

But I have absolutely no idea how to replace *[chosen directory]* with the value of the hidden input.

I've tried the following:

```
$("#uploader_v5").bind('BeforeUpload', function(uploader, file) {
    var directory = $('#directory').attr('id');
    uploader.settings.url = "pluploader/upload_to_directory.php?directory=" + directory;
});
```

The above gives me an *undefined variable* error for directory.

My knowledge of jQuery is very limited, so it may be something very simple, or perhaps an entire different way?

Comment: what is `$('#directory')`? in hidden input? div? or what?

Comment: @VijayHardaha it is <input type="hidden" id="directory" value="">

Comment: as it's an input then you'll get it's value using this `$('#directory').val();`

Comment: @VijayHardaha Okay I've tried $('#directory').val(); and the url still doesn't get updated. I've fiddled around and decided to write the directory path to a COOKIE, and retrieve it from the COOKIE again in the upload_to_directory.php file. This solution is not ideal, but it's getting the job done for now. Other suggestions are still welcome.